# Building a rolling date checker in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of accommodation data stored in BigQuery. One of the columns is a comma separated list of dates, corresponding to availability over the year:

```
Property1 | Hotel | 13/05/2021, 14/05/2021
Property2 | Hotel | 19/05/2021, 20/05/2021, 21/05/2021
```

For each property I want to create 365 rows, with each corresponding to a date of the year as shown below:

```
Property1 | Hotel | 12/05/2021 | FALSE
Property1 | Hotel | 13/05/2021 | TRUE
Property1 | Hotel | 14/05/2021 | TRUE
```

This data updates daily, so these rows will be increasing by 1 starting on today’s date. I'd be very grateful for any pointers on how this could be accomplished using SQL.

Comment: Where does TRUE/FALSE come from?

Comment: The data is output from a booking system. The dates here refer to the availability of the hotel over the year. So TRUE means available, FALSE unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below

```
WITH split_acco_data AS (
      SELECT prop_name, hotel_name,split(dates_str,',') AS dates_str
      FROM (SELECT * FROM mock_dataset.acco_data)
     )
SELECT prop_name, hotel_name,dates_str
FROM split_acco_data CROSS JOIN 
     UNNEST(split_acco_data.dates_str) AS dates_str;
```

Sample data in main table:

```
prop_name   hotel_name  dates_str       
Property1   Hotel        12/05/2021, 13/05/2021, 14/05/2021 
Property2   Hotel        19/05/2021, 20/05/2021, 21/05/2021
```

Output of query:

```
prop_name   hotel_name  dates_str
Property1   Hotel   12/05/2021
Property1   Hotel    13/05/2021
Property1   Hotel    14/05/2021
Property2   Hotel   19/05/2021
Property2   Hotel    20/05/2021
Property2   Hotel    21/05/2021
```

Comment: @lightfoot34 . . . You accepted this answer but it does not answer the question that you asked -- which is to generate a row for each day of the year with a flag.

Comment: @lightfoot34 - As i understand the flag is also available in your data in one of the column right? Although i didn't take that as column in my sample data. In the accomodation data you already have a column which has the flag available(TRUE) or not available (FALSE) right?.

Comment: I have added an `availability` column to the table I created using this query (`Table A`). I have since created a secondary table (`Table B`) with the full list of 365 dates for each hotel. I am now attempting to compare `Table A` with `Table B` and update the `availability` column in `Table A`.